# I want create a query builder page in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

> I am creating a query builder page in oracle apex.In this page some items are define like enter table name,enter column name,enter data type and one button.
>   I want that when i click on button and show create table syntax in next region.using item values.

Comment: Dude, you’ve gotta put some more effort into this. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: u have any idea related,how we can do this